# how to run a perl script after a html button onclick event

Tags: perl, cgi, forms

hi I'm new to Perl and CGI and HTML
I'm working on Linux and my apache is correctly configured. 
I have a simple program that should ask for your username and password, the input should come from a html file generated by my Perl script using the CGI module in perl. The user should then click on the "Login" button and this event should send these variables to another Perl script for authentication... my problem is sending these variables using the button's onClick property.
I've seen a lot of answers saying you should use the 'submit' button but i could not get this to work and a lot of answers saying you should use Javascripts but i also dont know how this works, please help!
this is my login perl script (Login.plx):

```
require 'Authentication.plx';

use CGI;
my $q = new CGI;

print $q->header;
print $q->start_html( -title => "Build Server");

print $q->h2("Login page");

print $q->start_form(
        -name       =>"Login_form",
        -method     =>"GET"
        -action     =>"Authentication.plx");

#Create textfield for Username, asigns value to $username
print $q->p("Name:");
print $q->textfield(-name=> 'usernameInput', -value=> 'Ockert', size=>20, -maxlength=>80);
my $username = $q->param('usernameInput');
#Create masked textfield for Password, asigns value to $password
print $q->p("Password:");
print $q->password_field(-name=>'passwordInput', -value=>'starting value',-size=>20,-maxlength=>80);
my $password = $q->param('passwordInput');
$password = crypt($password,12);

#call subAuthentication subroutine
print $q->submit(
    -name       => "btnLogin",
    -value      => "Login");

print $q->end_form;
print $q->end_html;
```

And the subAuthentication script (Authentication.plx):

```
use CGI;
my $q = new CGI;    

sub subAuthentication {

my $username = $q->param('$username');
my $password = $q->param('$password');

@return = ("Username not foud","Incorrect password","empty"); 

open(DATA,"<Users.txt") 
    or die "Can't open Users.txt";
$oneline = "";

foreach $oneline (<DATA>) {

    #print "\nValue of counter is $count\n";

    chomp($oneline);
    #print "oneline: $oneline\n";

    @oneline = split(',', $oneline, 3);

    #get administrator or user      
    $return[2] = $oneline[2];

    if ($username eq $oneline[0]) 
    {
        $return[0] = "true";
        ($password eq $oneline[1])? $return[1] = "true" : 0;
        last;
    }
}

close(DATA);

return @return;
}
```

Please help :)

Comment: "I've seen a lot of answers saying you should use the 'submit' button" — Yes, you should, that is exactly what submit buttons are for. —  "but i could not get this to word" — What code have you tried to achieve that? — "and a lot of answers saying you should use Javascripts" — That massively overcomplicates things while reducing reliability, don't do that.

Comment: thanks for the help @Quentin! I moved the start_form so that the form controls are inside the form... i still need help with the submit button, it does not submit the form correctly and then: how do i get the variables which i've send to Authentication.plx back to Login.plx?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your form controls **inside** the form.

As it is, you are calling `start_form` after you have already outputted the form controls.

---

You need to get the submitted values (with `->param`) in the script which you submit to, not the script that generates the HTML form. They won't be available until the form is submitted.

---

You should also use a regular submit button instead of a generic button with attached JavaScript.

If you were going to use attached JavaScript (via `onclick`) then it needs to be actual JavaScript and not Perl. Browsers don't support client side Perl.